# Sort DataGridColumn with null values always at bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, compare

I want a column in my DataGrid to sort with null values always at end.
I've tried to do this by following [this (part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/26/improving-microsoft-datagrid-ctp-sorting-performance.aspx) and [this (part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/28/improving-microsoft-datagrid-ctp-sorting-performance-part-2.aspx). But my custom sort doesn't work like I want.

Thats my compare method for my column :

```
private int NullableDateTimeCompare(DateTime? date1, DateTime? date2, int direction)
{
    if (date1.HasValue && date2.HasValue)
        return DateTime.Compare(date1.Value, date2.Value)*direction;
    if (!date1.HasValue && !date2.HasValue)
        return 0;
    if (date1.HasValue)
        return 1 * -direction; // Tried different things but nothing work like I will
    return -1 * -direction; // Tried different things but nothing work like I will
}
```

I've the impression that this doesn't work because DataGrid cached the Compare result and so inverse the sort when user sort (and don't run another time the Compare).

Have you an idea on how to do that ?

Thanks you !

Comment: If you always want the nulls at the bottom then comparisons between a null value and a non-null value should not be influenced by direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a simple project to share with you to explain my issue. And I found the solution.

It's like @juharr answer but the reverse.

```
if (date1.HasValue)
    return -1;
return 1;
```

Don't know why it must be like that but it works. Nulls are always on bottom.

So thanks to @juharr !

Comment: Is `date1` the first argument to the `IComparer.Compare` method, and `date2` the second.  If you swapped them then that would explain why you had to do the inverse.

Comment: I do not swapped them. That's why I find this weird.

Answer (score 1):

As you code currently stands the following will return 1

```
NullableDateTimeCompare(DateTime.Now, null, -1);
NullableDateTimeCompare(null, DateTime.Now, 1);
```

And these will return -1

```
NullableDateTimeCompare(DateTime.Now, null, 1);
NullableDateTimeCompare(null, DateTime.Now, -1);
```

But what you want is for these to return 1

```
NullableDateTimeCompare(DateTime.Now, null, -1);
NullableDateTimeCompare(DateTime.Now, null, 1);
```

and these to return -1

```
NullableDateTimeCompare(null, DateTime.Now, 1);
NullableDateTimeCompare(null, DateTime.Now, -1);
```

To achieve that just return 1 or -1 at the end of the function

```
if (date1.HasValue)
    return 1;
return -1;
```

Comment: I've tried this at first but it didn't work. So I've think that when ascending the null must get a high score and descend must have a low score. But it didn't work too...

Comment: The nulls should get a low or -1 if you want them at the end regardless of ascending or descending, which is what I assumed you wanted.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't work. Try yourself and see. You can download the example project from the link I gave in the description.